# calling a function after all ajax calls have ended inside a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble calling a function after all ajax calls have ended.

```
$("#popup").on("popupafteropen", function () {

$.ajax({}); //first ajax call
$.ajax({}); //second ajax call

$.when().then(function(){//DO SOMETHING});
```

Do I need create seperated functions for each ajax call for it to work?

Comment: `$.when($.ajax(), $.ajax()).done(function() {})` You need to pass the deferred/promise to `.when()`

Comment: @JasonP I'm quite new to ajax so I don't really understand what you mean by deferred and promised but inside the when brackets I need to write the number of ajax calls I make? Becuase if I write what you suggested, it still doesn't work for me

Comment: This isn't so much about ajax as it is about jQuery `deferred` functionality. It applies here because `$.ajax()` returns an object that can act like a deferred object. Try reading the documentation on `.when`(): https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ One of their examples looks like exactly what you're looking for: `$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) { ... `